# How to calculate top 3 contributors podium stand heights based on contribution percentages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

Consider the following top forum contributors podium: [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/khTrx/)

As you can see, the heights of the stands are constant. I would like to set the height according to the contribution percentage, so that if the first and the second places are 25.6% and 25.8% accordingly, the corresponding stands heights will be almost the same.

How would you calculate the heights based on contribution percentages ?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the height percent with the "%" in the value passed to the height function.

Change the calc_heights functions to as given below.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var first = 42.3;
    var second = 34.2;
    var third = 10.7;
    var heights = calc_heights(first, second, third);

    $(".first").height(heights[0] + "%").html(first);
    $(".second").height(heights[1] + "%").html(second);
    $(".third").height(heights[2] + "%").html(third);
});

function calc_heights(first, second, third) {
    var total = (first+second+third)/100;
    return [first/total, second/total, third/total];
}
```

Working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/khTrx/1/